# Better way to include a directory in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, macros, include-path

For my current CMake-project, i'm in need for the `numpy/ndarrayobject.h`-library. At first the project didn't compile and complained about `numpy/ndarrayobject.h` not being found in the include-path.

So what i did was `sudo find / -type f -name 'ndarrayobject.h'` and it spit out:

```
/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h
```

which i included in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/include/)
```

So, there is no actual error here. The project compiles and works as i expected it to. However, i think there must be a smarter way to find the directory. I have seen CMake-projects use

```
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

or something along these lines. So my initial thought is to learn about such macros to include the `numpy`-directory a bit smarter.

What are those macros called? Where are they defined? Where can i learn about them? Does such a macro exist for the above mentioned directory?

Is this maybe the wrong approach and there is a cleaner way to find and include the above mentioned directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, i think there must be a smarter way

Yes, you are right, and you are on the right track.

> What are those macros called? Where are they defined? Where can i learn about them?

Those are called "find modules", and are usually located in (assuming Unix/Linux): `/usr/local/share/cmake-<version>`. You can learn about them in the official documentation: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#find-modules

**However**: The ability to find NumPy seems to have been added in CMake 3.14: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/module/FindPython3.html.

So, assuming you are using CMake 3.14 or later, this should do the trick:

```
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS NumPy)
# Use PUBLIC or INTERFACE scope if you need to
# propagate the include folder to dependents
target_include_directories(<your target> PRIVATE ${Python3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Here we use `FindPython3.cmake`, which exports a whole heap of variables related to Python, including the one you need: `Python3_NumPy_INCLUDE_DIRS`.

**Edit**: As @Pedro correctly pointed out, you can also link to NumPy and get access to its include that way. **This is actually preferable**, since you may have to link to NumPy libraries anyway when building your application, and this saves you from having to issue two separate commands.

```
target_link_libraries(<your target> Python3::NumPy)
```

Now you can include said header: `#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>`

If you are unable to use CMake 3.14 or newer, you can consult the latest [find modules](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/tree/master/Modules) to see how it's done and simply write your own module, or build the latest CMake from source (which is trivial).

Comment: Hey, if you use CMake 3.14 or later, you may use also the imported target: `target_link_libraries(<your target> Python3::NumPy)` that takes care of your includes as well.

Comment: Thank you! I now have a `find_package`-call first followed by the `target_link_libraries`-call and it works as it should and looks very nice and portable.